# JW Player problems while loading nsv

Tags: html, jwplayer, audio-player

I'm trying to embed an nsv stream into jw player.
Unfortunately it doesn't work for Version 6+.
Can someone tell me why?

Link:
http://test.blackbeats.fm/streams/webplayer.php

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Webplayer</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': 'http://www.blackbeats.fm/webplayer/player.swf',
'file': 'http://stream.blackbeatslive.de/;stream.nsv',
'type': 'mp3',
'provider': 'sound',
'autostart': 'true',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'width': '470',
'height': '120'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's strange that it works with the following code and the older version of jw:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars =
{
'file': 'http://stream.blackbeatslive.de/;stream.nsv',
'title': 'My Stream',
'type': 'sound',
'duration': '99999',
'frontcolor': '86C29D', // text & icons (green)
'backcolor': '003367', // playlist background (blue)
'lightcolor': 'C286BA', // selected text/track highlight (red)
'screencolor': 'FFFFFF', // screen background (black)
'id': 'playerID',
'autostart': 'true',
'skin': 'kleur/kleur'

};

var params =
{
'allowfullscreen': 'true',
'allowscriptaccess': 'always',
'bgcolor': '#FFFFFF'
};

var attributes =
{
'id': 'playerID',
'name': 'playerID'
};

swfobject.embedSWF('player.swf', 'mediaspace', '600', '200', '9.0.124', false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to run this in JW6? Please note, we have not officially supported ShoutCast for a while now.

Comment: I updated the link: http://test.blackbeats.fm/streams/webplayer.php
Yes I know but it's a bit strange that it works with an older version..

Comment: This is still using 4.3...right click the player.

Comment: Have you made a page refresh? It's 6.4.33...

Comment: Delete this line - 'flashplayer': 'http://www.blackbeats.fm/webplayer/player.swf',

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, neither...

Comment: Your links seems to be working now?

Comment: Ah, I see that it's working in Firefox and Safari but in Chrome I still get an error... Any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: Set the primary variable to flash.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now! Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JW6, make sure to set the player's type variable to mp3 and the primary variable to flash, and this will work.

Comment: hey ethan, is it also possible to make this work on an iphone device?
I tried it using phonegap and jquery mobile but without success.
I guess setting the primary variable to flash forces this to not work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This won't work on iOS. We don't support it. This is kind of why we don't officially support this format since it doesn't work in Flash and HTML5 modes alike...

Comment: That's bad.. Yes, I'm aware of its minimal support. Anyway I've to deal with it as the client only have this format. Could you give me a hint how to play nsv files on IOS? I searched the whole internet but can't find anything..

Comment: There is no way to play NSV on iOS.

Comment: Ouh ok didn't know that.. Thanks! So I will try to find a solution to convert it to an another format..